# VSCode doesn't show error in case wrong syntax with context api

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I'm new to React and coming from Java + IntelliJ world feel VSCode doesn't capture basic error as below

```
const ProductContext = React.createContext;
```

After running code with above syntax; I got weird errors and after an hour I figured out that syntax should be

```
const ProductContext = React.createContext();
```

Is this bug with VSCode or I need to install some plugin to capture these kind of syntax errors ?

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript you can assign a function `createContext` to a variable. This is just the way Javascript works. But if you want tot assign the result from said function to `ProductContext` you need to call the function.

Regarding any plugins for VSCode. They won't capture this as this is valid syntax in js